# About details of app_ctx_stack and request_ctx_stack

Tags: python, flask

I wonder in flask 0.12, when can app_ctx_stack has more than 1 element and when can request_ctx_stack has more than 1 element? what is the purpose of RequestContext._implicit_app_ctx_stack?